# React Keyboard Events capturing with multiple components, priority and propagation

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-events, event-propagation

I have a page with `ComponentA`. I need `ComponentA` to react on keyboard key event with some function. Like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventLister // and so on
    return () => window.removeEventListener // and so on
}, [])
```

This is the easy part. But whenever there is `ComponentB` present and its input is in focus this listeners should not fire. There may be multiple `ComponentB` and `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` may be separated by another components. How should i approach this problem? My first idea was to create Context and send signals to it whenever input gets in focus or blured or destroyed, but may be there is a better solution?